# How do I maintain proper spacing after my element is dropped using react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, padding, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using `Material UI` with `react-beautiful-dnd` to create a pretty simple `Grid` column layout with elements that can be reordered. However, I'm having this jank issue with the spacing between the elements that's hard to explain, so I'll just show you a gif of it:

[image: Reordering]

I'm not sure where this issue could be coming from or even what to call it. Internally, the `spacing` property of `Grid` is implemented using `padding`, and I can't even find any information on why that wouldn't work with the drag and drop system. Here's the main part of the code:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Grid, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { produce } from "immer";

function ReorderQuestion(props) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.items);
  const classes = useStyles();

  function onDragEnd({ source, destination }) {
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setItems(
      produce(draft => {
        draft.splice(destination.index, 0, draft.splice(source.index, 1)[0]);
      })
    );
  }

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable droppableId="reorderQuestion" direction="horizontal">
        {provided => (
          <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
            <Grid spacing={3} container direction="row">
              {items.map((imageSrc, index) => (
                <Grid item key={imageSrc}>
                  <Draggable draggableId={imageSrc} index={index}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <Paper
                        innerRef={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        elevation={
                          snapshot.isDragging && !snapshot.isDropAnimating
                            ? 5
                            : 2
                        }
                        className={classes.option}
                      >
                        <img src={imageSrc} alt="Hiking" />
                      </Paper>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                </Grid>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </Grid>
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  option: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the solution, thanks to @mal#8537 on the Reactiflux Discord.

The issue is that the `innerRef` is being provided to the `Paper` component, which doesn't actually contain the spacing - ie, it doesn't use margins. The `Grid item`, its parent component, uses padding to achieve the spacing, therefore it must be moved inside the `Draggable` and provided with the `innerRef` (and the `draggableProps`) for the spacing to be dragged along correctly.

I simply replaced the inside of `items.map` with this:

```
<Draggable draggableId={imageSrc} index={index} key={imageSrc}>
    {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <Grid item
            innerRef={provided.innerRef} // PROVIDE REF HERE, TO GRID
            {...provided.draggableProps}>
          <Paper
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            elevation={
              snapshot.isDragging && !snapshot.isDropAnimating
                ? 5
                : 2
            }
            className={classes.option}
          >
            <img src={imageSrc} alt="Hiking" />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
    )}
</Draggable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted the solution proposed by @naiveal, but unfortunately it did not work for me. To address the issue, I added an extra div with a height equal to the margin height in the draggable element, which resolved the problem. While it may not be the most elegant solution, it did the job for me. I hope this workaround proves helpful to anyone else encountering a similar issue.

```
   <Draggable draggableId={id} index={index}>
      {(provided) => (
        <div
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        >
          {/* The extra div */}
          <div style={{ height: "1rem" }} /> 
           .....
        </div>
      )}
   </Draggable>
```